# how does instagram's custom navigation bar created?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on an iOS app and gonna work on the navigation controller part.
The UI of the navigation bar is not complex in my app; basically, it should have an app logo on the left an app name in the middle, and two bar button items on the right.

While I was researching, I saw the Instagram's navigation is sort of similar to what I want to try, especially the "Instagram" logo on the left.

I'm not sure if I can make a navigation bar like an instagram's navbar with a default UI navigation bar, so I guess I need to make a custom navigation bar with .xib file or something? or is it possible to make it with the default navigation bar and some codes??

If you can walk through the approach you take, please let me know...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with a default `UINavigationController`. For the logo you can create a `UIBarButtonItem` and set the image to whatever image you want (e.g a logo).

I have a function that sets the collection view's offset to 0 when tapping on the logo similar to Instagram.

For the 3 buttons on the right, you can do something like this:

```swift
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [button1, button2, button3]
```

Each button would be their own `UIBarButtonItem` and then add a selector to each of them.

Here is something similar to what I have in my app:

```swift
        let calendarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            image: UIImage(
                systemName: "calendar.badge"),
            style: .done,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(handleCalendarTap))
        
        let navLogoButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            image: UIImage(named: "nav-logo"),
            style: .plain,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(handleNavLogoTap))
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = calendarButtonItem
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logo
```

Comment: ahh, I didn't know that I can set multiple bar button items using an array. Will try this and see how it goes!

Comment: Yeah you can, done it many times. Let me know if you run into any issues!